# golang type conversion. interface to struct

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I am not used to `golang`.

When I requested, I got the below log.

I would like to parse the log and store into `struct` type.

Someone lets me know how to do?

Thanks in advance.

### for example :

```
type ResultStruct struct{
    id int
    guid string
    name string
}

for k, v := range data {
    fmt.Print(v.id) fmt.Print(v.guid) fmt.Print(v.name)
}
```

**[log]**

> data: [map[id:90001 guid:a name:test1] map[guid:b name:test2 id:90002] map[name:test3 id:90003 guid:c]]

**[source]**

```
response := httpClient.Do(request)
var data interface{}
rawdata, err := ioutil.ReadAll(response.body)
json.Unmarshal(rawdata, &data)
fmt.Println("data :", data)
```

Comment: Preferably you would log the `string(rawdata)`  instead of `data`. Json can easily be parsed and it is also quite readable.

Comment: I would like response data into struct type. Like below answer.

Comment: If an answer answered your question, please mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It is a common mistake for new Go programmers.

Because of language design, `json.Unmarshal` can only marshal into [*exported*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Exported_identifiers) fields.

Simply capitalize the first letter of each field name to export them. Optionally you may add field tags to tell json.Marshal what key-name to use. This is only needed if you are going to use `json.Marshal`.

```
type ResultStruct struct{
    Id   int    `json:"id"`
    Guid string `json:"guid"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
}
```

To quote the [`encoding/json` package](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal):

> To unmarshal JSON into a struct, Unmarshal matches incoming object
>   keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its
>   tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive
>   match. *Unmarshal will only set exported fields of the struct.*

Comment: Thanks for your kind explanation. Now i got it.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an Array, Unmarshal it using the `encoding/json` package.

```
type ResultStruct struct {
    id int      `json:"id"`
    guid string `json:"guid"`
    name string `json:"name"`
}
type Result struct {
    Data []ResultStruct `json:"data"`
}

response := httpClient.Do(request)
var data Result
decErr := json.NewDecoder(response.body).Decode(&data)
fmt.Println(decErr, data)
```

This should Unmarshal the data into array.

Comment: I did a test as your reply. But it prints none -" <nil> {[{0  } {0  } {0  }]} "

Comment: I did a test successfully. The problem was due to Naming. I named struct field UpperCase like Id, Guid, Name. Thanks for your help.